# Enviar dados do formulário via GET para servidor (sem atualizar página)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, get

Tenho esse formulário e gostaria de dar um `GET` para variaveis com o valor deles ao clicar no botão, sem dar refresh na página pois tenho outros formulários na mesma pagina, é possivel com PHP, ou tem que usar AJAX ?

**Layout do formulário**

[image: Formulario]

**HTML**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="control-label" contenteditable="true">
      Espaçamento entre linhas(metros):
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="input-mini" placeholder="1" id="linhas" value="1" disabled>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">
      Espaçamento entre plantas(metros):
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="plantas" placeholder="1" value="1" disabled>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="control-label">
      Tamanho da área a ser plantada:
    </label>
  </div>         
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <p>
      <input type="text" class="input-mini" id="tamanho">
      <select class="selectpicker">
        <option>ha</option>
        <option>m²</option>
      </select>
    </p>        
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Estimar</button>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Quer carregar de novo a página quando carrega em `Estomar` ou quer mandar esses dados para o PHP sem fazer refresh da página? (Coloque também o seu HTML por favor)

Comment: Acho que não me expressei bem,vou editar o post.Obg

Comment: A não ser que isso estaja numa iFrame vai precisar de AJAX. Qual prefer?

Comment: Prefiro o AJAX,pois não sei trabalhar com IFrame,o código Ajax pelo menos entenderei rs

Comment: E usa MooTools, jQuery ou outra biblioteca ou tem de ser JavaScript puro?

Comment: O unico framework que estou usando é bootstrap,pode ser jquery sim,não tem problema

Answer (score 5):

Fazendo uso de uma chamada AJAX recorrendo a jQuery para nos facilitar o trabalho, podemos lidar com a questão fazendo uso da função [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) da seguinte forma:

```js
var dadosFormulario = $("#formulario").serialize();

$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "caminho/para/ficheiro.php",
  data: dadosFormulario,
  success: function(resposta) {
    // variável "resposta" contém o que o servidor envia
    // aqui código a executar quando correu tudo bem
  },
  error: function() {
    // correu mal, agir em conformidade
  }
});
```

Ou o mesmo código numa forma mais portável onde para o efeito o HTML deverá estar perfeitamente válido:

```
var $form = $("#meuFormulario");

$.ajax({
  type: $form.attr("method"),  // GET ou POST definido no atributo "method" do formulário
  url: $form.attr("action"),   // URL para onde enviar os dados definido no atributo "action"
  data: $form.serialize(),
  success: function(resposta) {
    // variável "resposta" contém o que o servidor envia
    // aqui código a executar quando correu tudo bem
  },
  error: function() {
    // correu mal, agir em conformidade
  }
});
```

---

## Em detalhe

Para que seja possível fazer uso duma solução deste género, deverás ter em atenção algumas coisas:

1. Formulário deverá preferencialmente conter um atributo [`ID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#id) para o identificar de forma única na página:

   ```html
   <form id="meuFormulario" method="GET" action="http://www.meusite.com/ficheiro.php">
     <!-- ... -->
   </form>
   ```
2. Se o código da chamada de AJAX vai ser executado ao clicar num botão do tipo `submit` ou num `link`, através do método [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) ou outro do género, temos que evitar o comportamento normal desses elementos de forma a que a página não seja submetida para o servidor e/ou atualizada:

   ```js
   $('#meuBotao').on("click", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // chamada AJAX aqui
   });
   ```

   ou se estivermos a realizar a chamada AJAX diretamente na submissão do formulário, através do método [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) o conceito é o mesmo:

   ```js
   $('#meuFormulario').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     // chamada AJAX aqui
   });
   ```
3. Os elementos no formulário, para que sigam com um `$_GET` ou `$_POST` devem todos conter um atributo `name` cujo mesmo é o que os vai permitir serem identificados pelo servidor e assim recolher os seus valores:

   ```html
   <input type="text" name="meuNome" value="">
   ```

   De notar que estes nomes são identificadores únicos, com algumas exceções quando o objetivo é criar uma matriz de resultados ou como no caso de `radio` onde apenas um valor é devolvido de um conjunto deles.
4. No ficheiro `.php` para onde o AJAX vai enviar o `GET`, podes apanhar o mesmo da seguinte forma:

   ```php
   if (isset($_GET) && is_array($_GET)) {
     $meuNome = $_GET["meuNome"];
   }
   else {
     echo 'Ups... Preciso receber um GET e o mesmo deverá conter dados!';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('form').serialize();` ou `$('form').serializeArray();`

Comment: Quando há esse tipo de resposta, é aconselhável explicar porquê usar essas funções resolve o problema.