# Erro ao enviar dado de input para php com Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, input

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="username">
    <label>Usuário: </label>
    <p><?php echo $result[0]['username']; ?></p>
    <a>Editar</a>
    <input name="user" value="<?php echo $result[0]['username']; ?>" type="text">
    <button>Salvar</button>
    <span>Sucesso</span>
</div>
```

Estou enviando o conteúdo do `input user` para meu `php`:

```
$('div.username button').click(function() {
    $.post("forms/editprofile.php?edit=username", $("div.username input").val(), function(retorno) {
        if(retorno == "success") {
            $("div.username span").show('250');
        } else {
            $("div.username span").val("Falha").show('250');
        }
    });
});
```

E no `PHP` eu atualizo o meu registro com o valor recebido:

```
<?php
require_once '../libs/minpdo.php';
session_start();
$mnpdo = new MinPDO();
$edit = $_REQUEST['edit'];

if($edit == "username") {
    $user = $_REQUEST['user'];
    try {
        $mnpdo->update("users", "username", $user, "id = {$_SESSION['id']}");
        echo "success";
    } catch (MinPDOException $ex) {
        echo "fail";
    }   
}
```

A mensagem de Sucesso é exibida, porém vou no banco de dados e olho o registro, no campo `username` ele está vazio, provavelmente o erro está ou ao passar o dado ou ao receber:

Para passar:

```
$.post("forms/editprofile.php?edit=username", $("div.username input").val(), function(retorno) ....
```

Para receber:

```
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
```

Qual seria meu erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei outra forma descrita [aqui](http://tutsmais.com.br/blog/ajax/ajax-com-jquery-enviando-dados-via-ajax/) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41470/enviar-dados-do-formul%C3%A1rio-via-get-para-servidor-sem-atualizar-p%C3%A1gina), ficou assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "forms/editprofile.php?edit=username",
    data: "user=" + $("div.username input").val(),
    success: function(retorno) {
      $("div.username span").show('250');
    },
    error: function() {
      $("div.username span").val("Falha").show('250');
    }
  });
```

No lugar da linha `$.post ....`. Ou também alterando a linha para:

```
$.post("forms/editprofile.php?edit=username", "user=" + $("div.username input").val() ....
```